# C++ method that can return different templated types

Tags: c++, templates

So I have 2 classes, a templated class named `Node<T>` and a nontemplated one named `Context`. I have a few methods in Context that need to return any type of `Node<T>`.

For instance, sometimes it will need to return a `Node<double>` and sometimes an `Node<int>` etc. I also have some methods that I’d like to have that take any type of `Node<T>` as a parameter.

Is there any way I can do this that doesn’t include having separate methods in `Context` for each possible case?

```
class Node
{
  T Val;
public:
  Node(T value) : Val(val) {}
  T getVal() { return Val; } 
}

class Context
{
  Node<type>* divide(Node<type>* LHS, Node<type>* RHS)
  {
    type Solution LHS->getVal() / RHS->getVal();
    return new Node<type>(Solution);
  }
}
```

For instance, here, I want to return either a `Node<double>` if the answer ends up being a decimal, else I want to return a `Node<int>`. It will return a `Node<double>` with the solution as `Node->Val;` And other times, the operation will return an `Node<int>` (like `4/2`) so it will return a `Node<int>` instead. This is a cut down example of what I want to do but its the same idea.

Comment: sounds like a case for polymorphism

Comment: I think you need to be more desciptive.  You either want [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) or a [templated function](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)

Comment: "I have 2 objects, Object and Context." I guess you meant **classes**. "sometimes it will need to return a Object and sometimes an Object", please rephrase that. It sounds like you made a typo.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was in a rush and I didn't realize that the editor ignored my angle brackets (guess thought they were html tags). Anyway hope this helps more. I'm by no means a C++ expert so i'm not sure how using polymorphism will help me, if you could explain it that'd be great.

Comment: Is there a list of types you need to support as `T`, or just any type?  What determines which type you want to return?  Type `@user_name` to reply to someone (replacing `user_name` of course).

Comment: @Yakk: Just 3. Double int and char. It will vary depending on what types are passed. Sometimes if 2 Node< double > s are passed in, it'll return either a Node < double > or Node < int >.

Comment: Still too vague.  "are passed in" -- you mean, passed in to the same function?  Different functions?   "sometimes"?  Having a general idea of what you want to do is good, but you also want a very specific idea of what you want.  Edit your question to include an exact example of one case that would be sufficient to solve your problem, with no fuzzy-words: Then include a vaguer description of a what you want that is less narrow -- what you think is necessary.  Both are needed.

Comment: @Yakk: I'm sorry. Yeah passed into a method in the Context class. So I'm basically going to use these methods in Context to do operations on a value inside of Node< T > and based on what the operation evaluates to (For instance, my operation is the division of 2 ints, it will return an new Node < double > with the solution as Node->Val; And other times, the operation will return an int (like 4/2) so it will return a Node< int > instead. Does that help?

Comment: @Jrw3: A function taking the same parameters (two `Node<int>`s in both cases) must always return the same type.  So you either need type-erasure to return one type that "contains" one or the other, or unify the return types, or make them separate functions.  I highly recommend having `Node<int> / Node<int>` always return `Node<double>`, and adding an implicit conversion from `Node<double>` to `Node<int>`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thats kinda what I was thinking. I was hoping there was some hidden C++ism/feature that i wasn't' aware of to make that easier. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jrw3: There can be if the _values_ are known at compile time, but not otherwise.  Also there's type-erasure, but that ends up being tricky for the caller to properly use, and isn't worth the effort in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism as intended with virtual methods can't be achieved in C++ if you need different return types.. unless you use something like `boost::any` or return opaque `void *`.

For the way C++ works, if you need different return types you need different signatures and hence 2 different methods, however C++ has syntactic sugar for letting the compiler handling that (templates) so that the coder have just to write 1 method once.

```
template < typename T>
class Node{
    //...
};

class Container{


public:

    template< typename T>
    Node< T> * getNode(){

    }
};
```

a possible implementation:

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class Container{
    std::stack<void *> data;
    std::stack<std::string> names;
public:


    //push a node on the stack (you have to allocate it)
    template< typename T>
    void addNode( Node< T> * p){
        data.push(static_cast<void*>(p));
        names.push(typeid(T).name());
    }


    template< typename T>
    Node< T>* removeNode(){
        if(names.top()==typeid(T).name()){
            names.pop();
            Node< T>* node = reinterpret_cast<Node<T>*>(data.top());
            data.pop();
            return node;
        }
        return NULL; //returns nullptr;
    }
};
```

of course, this is just a working example (provided you have Node defined somewhere). To show you a possible way (literally that's the simplest example I can think of, but you can improve performance and use it to design the solution to your problem).

Usage example:

```
Container c;
Node<double> n1* = new Node<double>(5.0);
Node<double> n2* = new Node<double>(3.0);
Node<int>    n3* = new Node<int>(100);
c.addNode(n1);
c.addNode(n2);
c.addNode(n3); 
//since I used a stack now I check node in reversed order
cout<<     c.getNode<double>() == n3  <<endl; // false! n3 use "int"
cout<<     c.getNode<int>() == n3 <<endl; //true! 
cout<<     c.getNode<double>() == n2 <<endl; //true! 
cout<<     c.getNode<int>() == n1 <<endl; //false! n1 use double
cout<<     c.getNode<double>() == n1 <<endl; //true

delete n1;
delete n2;
delete n3;
```